# Jquery.get() Mixed Content when trying to fetch data without https

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I got the following code inside of one of my js functions to fetch new posts when user clicks `Load more` button

`$.get("/blog/page" + nextPage, function (data) {`

The code works fine when I test it locally.

When I push it to gh-pages it looks fine. But when I click `Load more` button, I get the following error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://username.github.io/sub-name/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://username.github.io/sub-name/blog/page2/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I've added `baseurl` to `_config.yml` file but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: could you add the repo? i have an idea (bad ref), but need code to confirm

Answer (score 0):

In https://railsr.github.io, you use `_includes/head.html` to access your `css` and `js` files are set to `http` from your `config` file. Use the protocol independent `//` instead

Comment: It's a private repo. Can't share it. I noticed that gh-pages forces to use https exaclty for this repo. But for eg http://railsr.github.io/autm-rb/ uses http. I tried switching it to public but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a different approach and now just have `posts.json` file in the root of the project which generates a list of posts.

```
---
---

[
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      {
        "title": "{{ post.title }}",
        "summary": "{{ post.summary }}",
         ...
      }
      {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

And then in one of my js files use

`$.getJSON("{{site.baseurl}}/posts.json", function(data) {`

and then push data to posts array and display posts in batches(load first 4 posts and then load another 4 per 'load more' button click)

(Without pagination)